# Which Book should I choose

Tags: books, tal

After watching a good deal of annotated games of Mikhail Tal on YouTube, I've finally decided to go in deeper by the means of 3 of his most famous books

- `Life and Games of Mikhail Tal`
- `Study Chess with Tal`
- `Attack with Tal`

Even after having bought all the three books, I don't know which one is the best...and sometimes the exercises become quite monotonous...what is your opinion?

Comment: What is your outcome? More importantly, what is your skill level? (Answer both questions.)

Comment: All the books??

Comment: What is your Chess ELO ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are looking for.

Personally I like *Attack with Mikhail Tal* best because it is really an excellent textbook (or guide, see the introduction) on how to play attacking chess. So if you are looking to improve your own game, this is the book I would recommend.

If on the other hand you are more interested in Tal himself and his career, his personality and style, then you should definitely go for *The Life and Games of Mikhail Tal*, which has much more comprehensive coverage of those aspects.